# Angular 4 how to inject svg

Tags: angular, svg

I have always used svg in  tags or as background-image.
Having recently followed : https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/
I would like to inject my svg directly. Has Angular4 any features allowing so ?

Comment: why would it be different from anything that you used to do ? did you tried any of your old solutions ?

Comment: ng-include doesn't exist in Angular4

Comment: you don't need such thing just use your svg in svg tag that's it. Or load it inside img tag or set the url in your css. I realy don't get it. Provide some code of what you tried.

Comment: yes as @jey mention there is no special treatment required if you just want to use svg as src for images or if you want to embed SVG into your views. You can check this article here to get more insights and some nuances: https://teropa.info/blog/2016/12/12/graphics-in-angular-2.html

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer:

As @osama-felfel pointed out, [the library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-inline-svg) indeed doesn't inject during build phase, but instead inject it as the component is loaded. I think this is even better, as it allow for the SVG to be downloaded in parallel.

For the bundle size comment by @user776686, it is [analyzed and contested here](https://github.com/arkon/ng-inline-svg/issues/92).

---

Original answer:

I guess you solved your problem, but I will post this here if anybody stumbles upon this. I used [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-inline-svg). It allows the svg to be injected during the build phase, so your css rules are applied.

Comment: Have you looked at your app's bundle size after installing this lib? On a fresh cli 6.0 app it bumps the bundle size from 170kb to over 400kb...  (`--prod --aot --build-optimizer`)

Comment: That plugin won't inject the svg during the build phase

Comment: @OsamaFelFel Did you read this part of [their readme](https://github.com/arkon/ng-inline-svg#server-side-rendering-with-angular-universal)? What are you using for SSR?

Comment: @joaoBeno Yes, I did read this part. It suggests that the SVG could be rendered on the server side which happens after receiving a request. What I need is to replace/inject the SVG during build/compile time. 

I don't know what do you mean by 'What are you using for SSR?'.